# Odoo 10 - Function and new object with onChange() decorator

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to have an explanation on this piece of code:

```
@api.onchange('foyer_id')
def get_responsibles_members_foyer(self):
    if self.foyer_id:
        actually_foyer = self.foyer_id.foyer_id
        partner_foyer = self.foyer_id.partner_id
        if actually_foyer:
            domain = [('foyer_id', '=', actually_foyer.id), ('partner_id', '=', partner_foyer.id)]
            records_foyer_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search(domain)
            # Récupéré les membres du foyers via les ids
            for rec in records_foyer_id:
                print " " + rec.partner_id.name
                if rec.partner_id:
                    domain_partner = [('foyer_id', '=', self.foyer_id.foyer_id.id),
                                      ('is_responsible', '=', True)]
                    records_partner_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search(domain_partner)
                    for rec_partner in records_partner_id:
                        if rec_partner.partner_id:
                            print "    " + rec_partner.partner_id.name
                            self.school_responsible_partner1 = rec_partner.partner_id.id
```

The purpose of this function is to recover the responsible member in a home and until then, it works.
So I act on the field foyer_id (which is a Many2one) and when the home is chosen, I get the good value in my field school_responsible_partner1

Now I want the focus to be automatically selected when opening a form with this code:

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def get_foyer(self):
    if self.partner_id:
        actually_partner_id = self.partner_id.name
        if actually_partner_id:
            records_foyer_id = self.env['horanet.relation.foyer'].search([('partner_id', '=', actually_partner_id)],
                                                                         order="id desc")
            for rec in records_foyer_id:
                self.foyer_id = rec.id
                print self.foyer_id
```

This function works because my fields foyer_id is filled automatically.

But on the other hand, and after adding this last function, the first function (get_responsibles_members_foyer) does not do its job anymore.

By debugging via PyCharm, I notice at this line:

partner_foyer = self.foyer_id.partner_id
that he finds a new object whereas previously he found the id of the partner.

Do you have an explanation ?

Thank you